# dataframe to have a list of values column and unique id without

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
C1      C2
abc1    def1
abc2    def2
abc3    def3
```

now dataframe can have huge number of rows and i have a list  where it can have many values and iterate over the whole dataframe  - suppose it has 2 values
list C3 ['d1','d2'] so basically the dataframe has to look like this

```
C1      C2     C3
abc1   def1    d1
abc2   def2    d1
abc3   def3    d1
abc1   def1    d2
abc2   def2    d2
abc3   def3    d2
```

now I don't want to iterate over the the whole dataframe, which I am doing now like after loop , is there a better way to achieve this

cant hard code the values in the list can have many values not only 2
some sample list - ['d5','d6','d7'] or anything ['bla', 'abc' , 'abaaa']

so have to write the code in such way that , how many values are there in the list that many times it will duplicate rows with another column which will have its value

Comment: So what's your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `np.repeat` for new column:

```
L = ['d5','d6','d7'] 

df = (pd.concat([df]*len(L), ignore_index=True)
        .assign(C3 = np.repeat(L, len(df))))
print (df)
     C1    C2  C3
0  abc1  def1  d5
1  abc2  def2  d5
2  abc3  def3  d5
3  abc1  def1  d6
4  abc2  def2  d6
5  abc3  def3  d6
6  abc1  def1  d7
7  abc2  def2  d7
8  abc3  def3  d7
```

Or use list comprehension with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df.assign(C3 = i) for i in L], ignore_index=True)
print (df)

     C1    C2  C3
0  abc1  def1  d5
1  abc2  def2  d5
2  abc3  def3  d5
3  abc1  def1  d6
4  abc2  def2  d6
5  abc3  def3  d6
6  abc1  def1  d7
7  abc2  def2  d7
8  abc3  def3  d7
```

Comment: the list can have many values - not just two

Comment: if there 3 or 4 values , how can i expect to write it

Comment: you have L[0] , L[1]. how will i know if the list has three values , i wont know , so have to write the code in such way that , how many values are there in the list that many times it will duplicate rows with another column which will have its value

Comment: it will duplicate rows 3 times and third column will have d5 and d6 and d7 value